# Not able to use std::sort with Android NDK

Tags: android, opencv, c++11, android-ndk

ndk-build always complains that the std::sort() has wrong arguments and in same message that it can't be found. Does the ndk use a other function?

> candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided    `sort(centroids.begin() + i * 10, centroids.begin() + (i + 1) * 10, pointXGreater);`
>
> error: no matching function for call to
>   'sort(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator*,
>   std::vector > >,
>   __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator*, std::vector > >, removeConvexity(cv::Mat, cv::Mat,
>   cv::Mat)::&)'

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    sort(centroids.begin() + i * 10, centroids.begin() + (i + 1) * 10, pointXGreater);
}
```

thats the function call.

```
vector<cv::Point> centroids;
centroids.reserve(100);

for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
    vector<cv::Point> contour = contours.at(i);
    Moments mom = moments(contour);
    cv::Point center = cv::Point(int(mom.m10 / mom.m00), int(mom.m01 / mom.m00));
    centroids.push_back(center);
}

std::reverse(centroids.begin(), centroids.end());

struct {
    bool operator()(const cv::Point p1, const cv::Point p2) {
        return p1.x < p2.x;
    }
} pointXGreater;
```

Somehow I was only able to compile it once. Now the problem came back.

Comment: #include <algorithm>?

Comment: How is `centroids` declared? and `pointXGreater`?

Comment: #include <algorithm> don't help. added declare

Comment: are you sure that centroids has always size 100?

Comment: its always 100 since its not possible that its bigger

Comment: anyhow, you should use `bool operator()(const cv::Point& p1, const cv::Point& p2) ...`

Comment: does a single call to `sort(centroids.begin() , centroids.end(), pointXGreater);` compile?

Comment: i can compile this in vs 2013 with no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static bool pointXGreater(const cv::Point p1, const cv::Point p2) 
{ 
    return p1.x < p2.x; 
} 
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
    sort(centroids.begin() + i * 10, centroids.begin() + (i + 1) * 10, pointXGreater); 
}
```

that solved the problem.